# Total value field if id is related in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I will sum value in top id (parent id), but i confused with grouping for it,

```
SELECT
  a.acct_no,
  SUM(IF(a.kode = 'D', a.nilai, 0)) AS nilai_debet,
  SUM(IF(a.kode = 'K', a.nilai, 0)) AS nilai_kredit
FROM tr2015 a
INNER JOIN acct2015 b ON a.acct_no = b.acct_no
WHERE
   a.hps <> '*' AND a.tgl LIKE '2015-01%'
GROUP BY
   a.acct_no 
ORDER BY
   a.acct_no
```

[my query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVcSe.jpg)

how i sum value nilai_debet (child id / like 100.01, 100.02, ..., 100.07) to parent id like 100 in a query ?

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: my questions updated, and look the image

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure but I feel you want to `SUM()` all values of `nilai_debet` which you can do in a outer query like

```
SELECT SUM(nilai_debet) AS Total_nilai_debet
FROM (
SELECT
  a.acct_no,
  SUM(IF(a.kode = 'D', a.nilai, 0)) AS nilai_debet,
  SUM(IF(a.kode = 'K', a.nilai, 0)) AS nilai_kredit
FROM tr2015 a
INNER JOIN acct2015 b ON a.acct_no = b.acct_no
WHERE
   a.hps <> '*' AND a.tgl LIKE '2015-01%'
GROUP BY
   a.acct_no 
ORDER BY
   a.acct_no) XXX;
```

Comment: but i want to sum and replace the value id parrent with total value in id child